# Wamp server only allows external connections from external ips

Tags: apache, server, ip, wampserver

It has been a while since I started using wampserver online, and until now it all went fine, but I recently started having a problem: I can access the server through a local ip (192.168.1.37 | 127.0.0.1 | localhost) if connected to my router or from my router's ip (e.g. 83.85.44.55) if im NOT connected to my router.

So basicaly if I'm connected to my router and try to access the servel with my router's external ip, I get a timeout error, whereas if someone from for example India tried to connect he would be able to do so.

I'm currently using wampserver 2.5 for windows with apache 2.4.9 and have already re-installed everything.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Elemermelada -

Port forwarding can be tricky when you are trying to access the server from multiple networks (i.e. your internal network and somewhere else on the internet). You are able to access the server with it's local IP because you are on the same subnet and there is no routing being done. When you attempt to connect to your webserver with your router's IP address, you are never making it to the webserver, regardless of the NAT/Port forwarding in place. The traffic is being dropped by your router because you are trying to access it from the inside. Unless you have a router that can be configured in a certain way, you will always need to connect to your webserver by it's local IP address when you are on it's local network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally reseted the router and now it works fine

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?" - IT Crowd

That's strange that something like that could have not worked for a time. Glad you got it sorted out!